# Winforms: bring 2 obscured forms to front

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I'm trying to solve this problem for a long time.
I have 2 forms, my objectives are:

1. When user minimize form2, form1 must minimize too.
2. When user maximize form2, form1 must maximize too.
3. When both forms are obscured by another window, and user clicks in the form2 icon in taskbar, form1 must also come to front.

The first 2 things I solved with the a_Resize method. But I can't do the third one. I tried with activate event but when I do that the form2 keeps blocked.
Here is my code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
        form2.Resize += new EventHandler(a_Resize);
    }

    void a_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((Form)sender).WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
        else
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
}
```

If I add a handler to the form2 activate event:

```
form2.Activated += new EventHandler(form2_Activated);
```

And call for instance the Focus method (I tried other methods too), the form2 keeps blocked behind form1.

```
void form2_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Focus();
}
```

Someone have any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: Two forms can't simultaneously be "active" or have the focus. Only one can be the foreground window. You'll have to pick one; which one do you want?

Comment: I don't think he's trying to make them both active; he just wants to make sure that when `form2` is activated, `form1` is also brought to the foreground as well (but still behind `form2`). Similar to if `form2` was a modal dialog with `form1` as the parent.

Comment: @Thiago: *try* to use `BringToFront()` instead of `Focus()`

Comment: @CodyGray: I need a behavior like ean5533 said. The user must see all forms in the application when activate one. The only form that needs to be active in this case is form2.

Comment: @Tigran: I tried that too but the form2 keeps blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create `form2`, just pass `this` as a parameter to `Show()` to signify that `form1` is the owner. With an owner link, the forms will always be raised together (at least in my experience -- I don't have a specification to back me up on this).

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show(this);     //pass 'this' as argument to Show() to link them
    form2.Resize += new EventHandler(a_Resize);
}
```

Comment: This is correct; when a form is owned by another form, it is closed or hidden (including minimized) with the owner form. Owned forms will never be displayed behind their owner form in the Z order.